# @WebMvcTest with MockMvc -- how to get MapStruct mapper bean instantiated and injected?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito, mapstruct

I'm trying to test a Spring Boot controller using MockMvc, as follows:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void getUser() throws Exception {
        when(myRepository.findByEmail("joe@abcdef.com"))
                .thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(
                        User.builder().email("joe@abcdef.com").id(12).build())
        );

        mockMvc.perform(get("/user/12"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value("joe@abcdef.com"));
    }
}
```

Now, the controller uses a MapStruct mapper which is injected.  Its definition:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING)
public interface UserMapper {
    User toEntity(UserDto userDto);

    UserDto toDto(User user);

    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    User partialUpdate(UserDto userDto, @MappingTarget User user);
}
```

When I run this test, I get:

> No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycompany.myproject.mappers.UserMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

How can I get this bean injected so that it can be picked up by the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)` adds only `MyController` to the application context and excludes all other beans.
You want to add at least [`@Import(UserMapper.class)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) plus any other beans your test requires to be in the application context.
If you don't require the real bean but want to mock it instead, add a field `@MockBean UserMapper userMapper` to your test class.

Read the relevant section from the [`@WebMvcTest` JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html#controllers()):

> Typically `@WebMvcTest` is used in combination with `@MockBean` or `@Import` to create any collaborators required by your `@Controller` beans.

Comment: I actually need to use @Import(UserMapperImpl.class), since MapStruct creates the implementation (via annotation) from the interface.  Thank you!